# Change Front page for anonymous user in sugarcrm?

Tags: sugarcrm

**What I Want ?**

I want my sugarcrm site Look like a normal site like any other site. on which their is Home, About us, Contact us and LOgin options are their?

**What I have done ?**

when I see the url of my site it look like **"localhost/crm/index.php?module=Users&action=Login**"  thats why I have created a custom module for contact us and home page. and try to fetch that  links through passing url.

**face Hurdle in it?**

Whatever I pass The link over it that was only open when  any user login into it. it does not open for Guest user.

**Please give some Idea about it.**

I have also try to chang the LDAP Authentication but I can`t understand the behaviour of LDAP authentication.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the answer that you are looking for, but SugarCRM is not a CMS but a CRM. It isn't meant to look and work like any other site. It is a business application. That being said there are always ways to manipulate the theme/layout to match your business' theme so that all your business apps have a similar theme for your organization's users. If you are looking at doing something with external users having access to SugarCRM I then highly advise using a portal that talks with SugarCRM via the API. There are Joomla, Drupal, and other 3rd party portal solutions that integrate with SugarCRM for this.